# 'No Image Named Pin.png for Index: 1'

Tags: ios, svn, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm integrating `MKMapKit` into my project.

I have messed with my subversion and frameworks, now when I load my `MapKit` I'm getting this:

```
'No Image Named Pin.png for Index: 1'
```

Code should work, nothing has changed. Just displaying a Map with 1 annotation to it.

Does somebody know what file or what setting I could have changed without purpose?

thanks in advance

Comment: may your device is jail-broken, I have this problem too.

Comment: No, certainly was not jailbroken. Issue is dated from a long time ago, just decided to not integrate apple maps. :)